# No file in target file on Macbook / write.csv function

Tags: r, dataframe, export

I am trying to export a dataframe as a CVS file on my Macbook (macOS Monterey 12.1) with the following function:

`write.csv(dataframe,file='/Users/admin/new_file.csv', row.names=FALSE)`

When I run the code, no error occurs but in the target file, no CSV file appears. I as well tried the readr write_csv() function but this does not work either.

The dataframe I would like to export has 66 columns and 2960 rows.

I would highly appreciate any recommendation about what the issue could be.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest, when you write the `file = ''` argument that you place the cursor inside the `' '`, and press TAB. That'll show you where you are within your working directory. Write a file name in there, and run the line - see if you can write *at all* and then perhaps we can diagnose whether it's the writing that's the issue or whether it's something to do with *where* you're trying to write.

Comment: You could also try putting a tilde in front of the file name, ie, `file = ‘~/Users/…’`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers! I tried it and it produces the following error: Warning: cannot open file ' /Users/admin\filename': No such file or directoryError in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection

Comment: How exactly are you checking if the file appears? Are you using the file browser? What does `file.exists("/Users/admin/new_file.csv")` return after you run the `write.csv`? If you are not getting an error it seems like the file must be created. Maybe you are just looking in the wrong place for it?

Comment: Found the file, so everything worked out - Thanks for your help!